# PHP multilevel categories to one line string

Tags: php, function

I would like to make **function what can return** me complete **structure of categories as string delimited by " > "** in simple array.

For example I added here simple image of mine DB structure and I need to get from this structure data like this:

```
Cars
Cars > Alfa Romeo
Cars > Audi
Cars > BMW
Cars > BMW > 1
Cars > BMW > 1 > 2004-2013
Cars > BMW > 1 > od 2011 (F20/F21)
Cars > BMW > 2
Cars > Chevrolet
Cars > Chrysler
Cars > Citroen
Cars > Dacia
```

Can anyone give me hint how can I do this ? Thanks in advance.

[image: DB categories]

Comment: Are you trying to build the array from the database?

Comment: I need in final this array: [Imgur](https://imgur.com/kDy5JeA)

Comment: that doesn't answer my question though. Do you already have this array or is that the goal (i.e to get to that array).

Comment: this is the goal

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to redesign your database schema with the approach of keeping the data atomic and separated.

What I see on your example is an all-in-one table. This is simple table but makes it complicates both data maintenance and database queries. Imagine you will want to add another top level category bikes, houses, mobiles, ...

Better approach is to create separate tables

- `category` with columns `id`, `cat_name`
- `brand` with column `id`, `,cat_id`, `brand_name`
- `item` with columns `id`, `brand_id`, `item_name`
- `note` with columns `id`, `item_id`, `note_details`

This way you will be able to list anything right from the database and then just send it to the browser.

```
SELECT category_name, brand_name, item_name, note_details 
FROM category
LEFT JOIN brand ON brand.category_id = category.id
LEFT JOIN item ON item.brand_id = brand.id
LEFT JOIN note ON note.item_id = item.id
```

Output:

```
category_name   brand_name  item_name   note_details
Cars    BMW     1   2004-2013
Cars    BMW     1   od 2011 (F20/F21)
Cars    BMW     2   (null)
...
```

Some filters use in WHERE:

```
-- List all devices by brand 
WHERE brand_name = 'Tesla'
```

Output:

```
category_name   brand_name  item_name   note_details
Cars            Tesla   Truck   Silver car
Television      Tesla   1       Color TV


-- List only specific car
WHERE category_name = 'Cars' AND brand_name = 'BMW' AND item_name = '1'
```

Output:

```
category_name   brand_name  item_name   note_details
Cars            BMW     1   2004-2013
Cars            BMW     1   od 2011 (F20/F21)
```

[Live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fdd88b/1/0)